# mainActivity gets distroyed if initial orientation is landscape on Android

Tags: android, screen-orientation

I am working on an app where all activities are set to:

```
   android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

Here is what happens:

> Tablet is in portrait mode BEFORE the app starts:

- startScreen is created in portrait mode
- one navigates to another portrait screen
- one goes back to startScreen - it gets created in portrait mode - everything OK

> And this is what happens when the tablet is in landscape mode when
>   the app starts:

- startScreen is created in portrait mode
- one navigates to another portrait screen
- one goes back to startScreen - it gets created in LANDSCAPE mode only to be immediately closed within a fraction of a second  and the activity gets distroyed - then finally the activity gets created in porttrait mode

**How can I avoid this creation in LANDSCAPE mode for a fraction of a second and immediately be created in portrait mode only?**

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add in your manifest in the activity tag: android:configChanges="orientation". Now it will not restart in the orientation.

This is a theory only, but if you see your screen in landscape mode first you you can perhaps override your root view and override the onDraw method. 
Check your canvas width and height. 
If the height is bigger smaller than width don't draw or set visibility false.
Until you receive the "right" canvas to draw upon.

It might be an overkill but I think it might be done.

Also look for more possible things that can change screen orientation here:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#screen

There is another one from API 14 and up (I think) that caused me a lot of problem which is "ScreenSize".

Comment: that's better now - at least the initialScreen activity does not get destroyed - however, it still creates landscape first and then turns to portrait... (By the way I am using 3.1 level 12, in case it matters)

Comment: That's odd. It creates and then destroys it (goes through the activity life cycle) or you just see it for a second then it goes to portrait (without going through the life cycle)? Also I edited my answer and added another thing that can cause restart and maybe a fix for not seeing landscape first.

Answer (score 0):

Create your Activity in portrait mode and change to landscape mode in the `onResume` method.

```
myActivity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```

Comment: I don't understand - I want my activity to remain in portrait - not in landscape. Anyway, I created onResume and set to portrait mode, still the screen gets created in landscape first, distroyed, recreated in portrait....

Comment: What happens when you do this in the `onCreate`? Does it still switch?